# В ответе один ключ используется много раз

Tags: python

Вот response:

```
{"response":{"trade_offers_sent":[{"tradeofferid":"3688672517","accountid_other":484947526,"message":"TPA9 ... /trade/2774573977/MhHeod5FnmY/","expiration_time":1568380970,"trade_offer_state":4,}{"tradeofferid":"3688571692","accountid_other":5551133,"message":"UQTM ... /trade/2774290053/KYrUQ0lVCFw/","expiration_time":1568375852,"trade_offer_state":3,}
```

в этом респонсе мне надо узнать,допустим tradeofferid во втором обмене.Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp
это обычные json вот почитай по ссылке

Comment: Я увидел такой экзампл:import json

x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "divorced": False,
  "children": ("Ann","Billy"),
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
    {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
  ]
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

# the result is a JSON string:
print(y)

Ответ такой:
{"name": "John", "age": 30, "married": true, "divorced": false, "children": ["Ann","Billy"], "pets": null, "cars": [{"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5}, {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}]}
Как мне сравнить эти model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что Вы привели в вопросе не является `Json`'ом. В вашем ответе используются завершающие запятые, а также не совпадает количество открывающих и закрывающих скобок. Я думаю, Вы опечатались при копировании.

Если предположить, что Вы имели в виду это:

```
{
    "response": {
        "trade_offers_sent": [{
            "tradeofferid": "3688672517",
            "accountid_other": 484947526,
            "message": "TPA9 ... /trade/2774573977/MhHeod5FnmY/",
            "expiration_time": 1568380970,
            "trade_offer_state": 4
        }, {
            "tradeofferid": "3688571692",
            "accountid_other": 5551133,
            "expiration_time": 1568375852,
            "trade_offer_state": 3
        }]
    }
}
```

то Вы можете распарсить ответ с помощью модуля `json`.

***Пример:***

```py
import json


# Я добавил запятые и закрыл скобки, чтобы это стало валидным Json
response = '{"response":{"trade_offers_sent":[{"tradeofferid":"3688672517","accountid_other":484947526,"message":"TPA9 ... /trade/2774573977/MhHeod5FnmY/","expiration_time":1568380970,"trade_offer_state":4},{"tradeofferid":"3688571692","accountid_other":5551133,"expiration_time":1568375852,"trade_offer_state":3}]}}'
d = json.loads(response)

tradeofferid = d['response']['trade_offers_sent'][1]['tradeofferid']
print(tradeofferid)
```

***stdout:***

```html
3688571692
```

Comment: Спасибо,не так много опыта в этой теме,но развиваюсь

Comment: А можно узнать сколько всего таких элементов в списке?

Comment: @artemso72 — `len(d['response']['trade_offers_sent'])`